# XCode and GitStack

Tags: ios, xcode, gitstack

I installed GitStack server on my Windows server 2008 machine, created a repository, created a user, and I can browse to the repository from my local machine.
The problem is that when I go to my Mac, I can browse through the web fine, but when I open the XCode and try to connect to the repository, it prompts me for the name and password and just keeps prompting, but cannot log me in. Is this GitStack related, or something with my XCode? I use XCode 4.6.2.

I used this:

```
https://testname@192.168.1.10/reponame
https://testname@192.168.1.10/reponame
https://testname:testpassword@192.168.1.10/reponame
```

Nothing works, it always prompts me for the name and password and cannot log in. This user is created as local user in GitStack, and had been given the access to the repository.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you share your C:/GitStack/apache/logs/error.log file?

Answer (score 0):

Try to initialize the git repository through Terminal.
It must be something about security and in Terminal you'll have a prompt.